# Why didn't webview in Android support creating array by []

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, webview

I have a javascript code to create an array as below:

```
let array = []
```

when I run this code in a webview in android5.0.0. I got below error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined
```

if I change it to

```
let array = new Array()
```

it works fine. Doesn't android webview support creating array by []? How can I let the webview support it? otherwise, i have to change my source code a lot in order to be compatible with the webview.

[EDIT1]
I have used babel to convert my javascript code to ES5 syntax.